# Asp.net core Identity multiple roles to user

Tags: asp.net-core, identity, claims-based-identity, policy, role-base-authorization

I am working on asp.net core 3.1 project. There are several types of users in project. For example :

**Some of users type**

Admin

writer

Manager

Accountants

Operator

and ...

Users type are different and may increase or decrease. We may have 20 writers or 100 operators users in this project that all writers or all operators have same roles.
Now i can set roles to user manually. But i want to set a bunch of roles to users.
For example if user type was operator all roles depends on operator set to user.

Comment: Each user can be assigned multiple roles

Comment: @citronas Yes i know it. I would like to have all manager roles if I designate a user to manager. That means to set roles to the user type and the user type to the user

Answer (score 1):

I create a simple demo which you could choose `UserType` when you register a user. And assign all related roles of the `UserType` to user.

1.Models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [ForeignKey("UserType")]
    public int UserTypeId {get;set;}
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
}

public class UserType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    [ForeignKey("UserType")]
    public int? UserTypeId {get;set;}
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
}
```

2.DbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationRole> AppRoles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasOne(c => c.UserType)
        .WithMany(u=>u.Users)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);


    }
}
```

3.Register.cshtml.cs

```
public class InputModel
    {

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
    }

public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {

        ViewData["UserType"] = new SelectList(_context.UserTypes, "Id", "Name");

        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {

        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email, UserTypeId = Input.UserTypeId };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //add bunch of roles to user
                var roles = _context.AppRoles.Where(r => r.UserTypeId == user.UserTypeId).Select(r => r.Name).ToList();
                foreach(var role in roles)
                {
                   await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
                }

               //...
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
```

4.Register.cshtml

```
<form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
        <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
            <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
            <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
            <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Input.UserTypeId"></label>
            <select asp-for="Input.UserTypeId" asp-items="@ViewBag.UserType" class="form-control"></select>

        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
 </form>
```

4.Startup.cs

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```